# Bitnami (Moodle) container won't run on M1: "Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, moodle, apple-m1, bitnami

I want to run a Bitnami container on Apple M1. My question is about [Bitnami Moodle](https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle), however, I suspect my problem to be rather general as it occurs when starting Apache.

*error message*:

```
(95)Operation not supported: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex
```

I added `platform: linux/amd64` and added a Dockerfile:

*from docker-compose.yml*

```
moodle:
  platform: linux/amd64
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  image: bitnami/moodle:4
```

*Dockerfile* (see [this source](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/issues/316#issuecomment-1088027256)):

```
FROM bitnami/moodle
RUN echo 'Mutex posixsem' >>/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

I also tried adding the `--platform` argument when building: `docker build --no-cache --platform=linux/amd64 .`

None of this helps. I can see relevant output when running `docker build .` (*[2/3] RUN echo 'Mutex posixsem' ...*), but I keep getting the same error when running `docker-compose up`.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: I have the same error, Do you did it?

Comment: @felixmpa I added an answer that might help you

Answer (score 2):

I put this problem aside for a while, but this is the relevant (and working) part from `docker-compose.yml` we are currently using with Linux, as well as M1 and M2 MacBooks.

```
services:
  moodle:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    container_name: foo_moodle
    depends_on:
      - moodle_db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_TYPE=pgsql
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST=moodle_db
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=5432
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_USER=${MOODLE_DB_USER}
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME=${MOODLE_DB_NAME}
      - MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${MOODLE_DB_PASS}
      - MOODLE_SITE_NAME=${MOODLE_SITE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./moodle/mount_moodle:/bitnami/moodle
      - ./moodle/mount_moodle_data:/bitnami/moodledata

  moodle_db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: bitnami/postgresql:14
    container_name: foo_moodle_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 54322:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=${MOODLE_DB_USER}
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=${MOODLE_DB_PASS}
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=${MOODLE_DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./moodle/mount_moodle_db:/bitnami/postgresql
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/moodle:4.1.2

# Needed to work on Mac
# Some credit goes to: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/16977/server-fails-after-installing-certbot-mpm-run-failed-exiting#answer-66578
RUN echo 'Mutex posixsem' >>/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```